# How to make messages stay for interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 4 messages which are made to fade In and Out, but I need to set interval so they can be read. I mean in fades in for 500ms then stays like 2000ms and then fades out for 1500ms.

```
var messages = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3', 'message4'];
var i = 0;

function doFade() {
    $('#text').fadeOut(1500, function() {
        $(this).html(messages[i % messages.length]);
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the delay function in jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

i.e.

```
$("#text").fadeOut(1500, function(){ 
    $(this).html(messages[i % messages.length]);
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Although the native javascript setTimeout could also achieve this.

I created a simple jsFiddle using combination of setTimeout and the delay method in jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/uzm3h/3/